# Controller doesn't response to the button on the website

Tags: java, jquery, html, spring-mvc, controller

I'm new to frontend, there is a div block on my website which is based on thymeleaf, and I created a button in it, here is the html code, please focus on the button which on the last three rows,

```
<form th:action="@{/quiz/nextQuestion}" th:object="${answeredQuestion}" method="post">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <h3 th:text="${questionStem}">which is the best answer</h3>
      <div class="skin skin-square">
        <div class="skin-section">        
          <ul class="list">
            <li th:each="option,rowStat : ${options}">
              <input tabindex="11" type="radio" th:id="${rowStat.index}" name="square-radio"></input>
              <label th:for="${rowStat.index}" th:text="${option.optionString}" >option 1</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>          
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.skin-square input').iCheck({
                checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
                radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
                increaseArea: '20%'
              });
            });
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layout-onright-30">
        <button type="button" class="btn default" action="submit">Next One</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Following is my controller,

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RequestMapping("/quiz")
@Import({ QuizServiceImpl.class, QuestionServiceImpl.class })
public class ExamController {
    private static UUID testVariable = null;
    @RequestMapping(value = "/nextQuestion", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doNextQuestion(@ModelAttribute("answeredQuestion") AnsweredQuestion answeredQuestion) {
        System.out.println("run in next ques");
        Question question = quizService
                .getNextQuestion(null, testVariable);
        System.out.println(question.toString());
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("examination");
        ChoiceQuestion choiceQuestion = (ChoiceQuestion) question;
        modelAndView.addObject("questionStem", choiceQuestion.getQuestionStem());
        modelAndView.addObject("options", choiceQuestion.getOptions());
        return modelAndView;        
    }
}
```

Additional information, the `answeredQuestion` is a empty class without any method or member.

The issue is, when I click the button `Next One`, there is no any response from the controller, what I used is spring boot, I'm sure service and controller are all up.

Could anyone help me with it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does something happen in the UI (like form getting submitted)? Can you enable logging and see if the form submission (if it happens) is able to match the appropriate controller? Once you find whether the request is going and till where it's going, you might be able to solve this yourself.

Comment: Thank you @prabugp , it's good to me, followed your advice, I find the answer that there is no submission happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in the html, and I figure it our followed the advice from @prabugp .

Change the line:

```
<button type="button" class="btn default" action="submit">Next One</button>
```

to:

```
<button class="btn default" type="submit">Next One</button>
```

It works. It's a typo.